# Include Libraries in Visual Studio for Other PCs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm fairly new to C++ and I know how to link external libraries in Visual Studio, but I'm not sure how to include them with the .exe file that is made when you build. How do I include a library with that so the other PC doesn't have to have the libraries installed in the same exact location on the disk that I do (or in other words just with the application)? I tried putting the .dll files directly with the .exe but it says it can't locate them.

Comment: If they are external dlls, then you generally make an installer that puts the exe, dlls, and other files at a specific location (e.g. program files) along with modifying other things such as the registry or AppData as needed.

Comment: You don't need to modify the registry to find linked DLL's !

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the type of linkage that you use for the library. You basicaly have 2 options:

- static linking
- dynamic linking

When you *statically* link your program with a library, that library is embedded into the resulting application (exe). So you need to distribute only that resulting application.

Or the library can be linked *dynamically*. This means that the actual library code will be looked up at runtime (by OS) from *dll* file (on Windows). In this case you must be sure, that user will have *dll*s you need on their computer. To see where Windows searches for *dll*s see this [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx). Basically you want your *dll*s to reside in the folder, where your program is, so Widnows can find it. Or if you are using some system libraries (e.g. Direct3D) your user will probably have those *dll*s already installed.